# Connecting SQL Server 2012 to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have 2 devices, a server computer installed with SQL Server 2012, and a raspberry pi with MySQL installed. I have data in MySQL tables. How can I connect SQL Server 2012 to MySQL so I can save that data?

Comment: Linked Server via ODBC connection?  https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-a-linked-server-using-the-odbc-driver/

Comment: i have to install the ODBC software in both devices? raspberry device its a Linux OS.

Comment: Shouldn't have to install on the Pi as long as there is a port open on it.  Research to see what the standard port is for MySql.  Looks like it's 3306?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-standard.html  So the provider might just be *IPAddress*:3306\SID

Comment: the only way to do it, its using ODBC? or there are differents ways ?

Comment: Sure, I'm sure there are other ways like SSIS, DataStage, and other ETL tools.  If it was cross-database with the same platform, you'd be okay.  If it's cross-PLATFORM, you'll have to go with the easiest translation, which is usually ODBC.

Comment: Thanks so much, i did the connection using ODBC... works really good!

Comment: Sure thing.  Go ahead and make a new answer to this question, then mark it as the answer.  This will help other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is with HeidiSQL, which can connect to SQL Server and MySQL and is free and open source (https://www.heidisql.com/). Once you set up both connections, you can use the **Export Database As SQL** feature to transfer data directly between databases.

- In the Session Manager, set up the connection to the MySQL and SQL Server computers
- Connect to the MySQL server, right-click on the server in the browser on the left, and select "Export Database As SQL".
- in the table list, select the table(s) you would like to export
- in the Output: on the right, you will see a list of all servers you have configured in the Session Manager. Select the SQL Server 2012 instance.
- You will probably want to keep the database the same so leave it as [Same as on source server]
- You likely will want to check the create boxes for both database and tables if this is the 1st time you are transferring data
- If you want to transfer the data and not just the table structure, in the Data: dropdown select the option that is best for you. I usually use Delete + insert (truncate existing data), but your needs may be different.
- Click Export in the bottom right

That should do it.